# Different let in for lines in do block

Tags: haskell, let, do-notation

I want to create some tests with varying values, using hspec. I wrote the following code which does not compile but give an idea of what I am aiming at:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
    describe "productOneLine" $ do
        let
            inVector = Data.Vector.replicate 0 0
            inInteger = 3
            outVector = Data.Vector.replicate 1 0
        in
            it "must manage empty vector" $ productOneLine inVector inInteger `shouldBe` outVector
        let
            inVector = Data.Vector.fromList [2, 4, 5]
            inInteger = 4
            outVector = Data.Vector.fromList [9, 6, 1, 2]
        in
            it "must multiply a vector by an integer" $ productOneLine inVector inInteger `shouldBe` outVector
```

How can I create different sets of `inVector`, `inInteger` et `outVector` for each ligne beginning with `it` ?

Comment: Does this help? https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/05/07/inlined-hunit-test-lists

Comment: Thank you. However I would like to know how to insert `let` `in` or `where` for individual lines in a `do` block.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info and the answer linked therein. `let ... in ...` is just an expression. expressions belong to the "action" parts of the `do` block.

Comment: there is no `where` in `do` blocks.

Comment: The indentation is wrong, `in` should be indented forward more than `let`. The reason is that the `do` block has a `let` variant without `in`. So the compiler interprets your `let`s as such variant, because it doesn't see `in` right away, and then `in` on the next line comes `in` unexpectedly). Otherwise it isn't clear what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Not super relevant to what you're actually asking, but you could use `it "must manage empty vector" $ let ... in productOneLne ...` (obviously over more lines, which I can't do in comment). That might be a bit more readable for visually putting the test-local definitions "within" the test case introduced by its description, rather than putting the test description visually deeper inside the test case, after the local definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're getting the error:

```
parse error on input `in'
```

the problem is just indentation, as per @n.`pronouns'm.'s comment.

In most cases, a `let` block can be written with the `let` and `in` keywords lining up:

```
foo a b = let a2 = a*a
              b2 = b*b
          in a2 + b2
          ^
          `- let and in starting at same column
```

In fact, the `in` can be less indented than the `let`, it just needs to be indented more than the `foo`:

```
foo a b = let a2 = a*a
              b2 = b*b
  in a2 + b2
```

However, in a `do` block, an `in`-less `let` statement is allowed:

```
main = do
  let s = "Hello"
  putStrLn s
```

If you try to write:

```
main = do
  let s = "Hello"
  in PutStrLn s
```

the `let s = "Hello"` is parsed as a `let` statement, and the `in PutStrLn s` is parsed as a second `do` statement, with invalid syntax as it starts with the reserved word `in`.

You can write:

```
main = do
  let s = "Hello" in
    putStrLn s
```

or:

```
main = do
  let s = "Hello"
    in putStrLn s
```

or:

```
main = do
  let s = "Hello"
    in 
    putStrLn s
```

In each case, the indention will cause the entire expression `let ... in ...` to be parsed as a single expression, which is itself a valid `do`-statement.   Combining two such statements is easy enough:

```
main = do
  let s = "Hello"
    in
    putStrLn s
  let s = "Goodbye"
    in
    putStrLn s
```

Answer (score 3):

K. A. Buhr's answer is entirely correct. I'm adding this answer as a complementary description of what's going on in terms of Haskell's layout rules, which may help reason it out when a similar problem happens in a different context.

Almost all of Haskell's syntax is completely insensitive to indentation, but there are a few constructs that use alignment to indicate the entries within blocks of statements or definitions. `do` blocks are one such context. The rules are the same for all of them, though.

1. Each block has an alignment position for its entries. The position is set by the first non-whitespace character following the keyword introducing the block (regardless of whether it's own the same line or a following line).
2. A line indented to exactly the same alignment is the beginning of an "entry" in the block.
3. A line indented more than the alignment has no particular meaning; it's just part of an entry that started on an earlier line.
4. A line indented less than the alignment position indicates the end of the block (and is **not** itself part of the block, so it must be part of some enclosing syntax, which may or may not be an aligned block)

A consequence of this that may not be obvious is that when an entry in a block spans more than one line itself, every one of the continuation lines must be further indented than the first. If a continuation line was indented the same as the first, it would be taken as starting a new entry in the block instead of continuing an existing one, and if it was indented less it would be taken as indicating the end of the entire block.

How this applies to the OP's example is pretty straightforward.

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
    describe "productOneLine" $ do
        let
            inVector = Data.Vector.replicate 0 0
            inInteger = 3
            outVector = Data.Vector.replicate 1 0
        in
            it "must manage empty vector" $ productOneLine inVector inInteger `shouldBe` outVector
        let
            inVector = Data.Vector.fromList [2, 4, 5]
            inInteger = 4
            outVector = Data.Vector.fromList [9, 6, 1, 2]
        in
            it "must multiply a vector by an integer" $ productOneLine inVector inInteger `shouldBe` outVector
```

The first character following the `do` keyword is the l in `let` (on the next line). So we can immediately see that this `do` block has 4 entries, starting with `let`, `in`, `let`, and `in`.

That's not what the OP intended; they wanted there to be 2 entries, each of which is a complete `let ... in ...` expression. To make that happen, the `in` keywords need to be further indented.

It **does not matter** that `let ... in ...` itself is a construct that uses aligned indentation. There's nothing in the above rules that would require `in` to be aligned with the `let`. The alignment position is the first character of the first declaration inside them (the i in `inVector` in each case), not the position of the `l` and it applies only to the block of declarations, not to the `in` part of the overall `let ... in ...` expression.

And in fact the `in` keyword of `let ... in ...` is totally insensitive to indentation. It can go anywhere (so long as it doesn't fall foul of an alignment set by an enclosing block, as happened in the OP's example). You can do this<sup>1</sup>:

```
three = let x = 1
            y = 2
  in x + y
```

Or this<sup>2</sup>:

```
five = let x = 2
           y = 3 in x + y
```

Either way layout rules aren't necessary to tell that `in` keyword isn't part of the declaration block, only to tell where the beginning of each declaration in the block is.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is only one constraint on the placement of the `in` in this example. It can't go right at the beginning of the line, which is only because the global definitions in the module (spanning the entire file) actually are an aligned block! You just usually don't notice this, because it's conventional to use an alignment of zero indentation for this block.

<sup>2</sup> My usual style is this:

```
seven
  = let x = 3
        y = 4
     in x + y
```

which happens to work inside a `do` block without adjustment, a bonus I had never noticed before.